# Bing Search API Statistics

Tags: azure, statistics, bing

This might be a simple question, but I cannot figure it out. I have implemented the Bing Search API on our site and are very happy with it. However, we do not want to continue paying for it if we can't figure out the statistical capabilities.

Is there a way to see or export all search results AND see if it was a success or failure? Success being results showed up for a searched term. A failure being no results showing up (i.e. No Results Found page).

In addition, does error code 400 mean no results showed? If anyone could help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The [Bing Search APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/) let you build web-connected apps and services that find webpages, images, news, locations, and more without advertisements. By sending search requests using the Bing Search REST APIs or SDKs, you can get relevant information and content for web searches.

Responses from the Bing Web Search API are returned as JSON.
[image]

The following helps for bing [search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/) and [statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/bing-web-stats).  .